# Como puedo poner las preguntas de un formulario html y que salga 1 por pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

```
<label for="Pregunta1">¿Siente que su familiar solicita más ayuda de la que realmente necesita?</label>
            <select id = "Pregunta1" name="Pregunta1">
                <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                <option value="2">A veces</option>
                <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
            </select>

<label for="Pregunta2">¿Siente que debido al tiempo que dedica a su familiar ya no dispone de tiempo suficiente para usted?</label>
<select id = "Pregunta2" name="Pregunta2">
                <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                <option value="2">A veces</option>
                <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
</select>
```

Las preguntas son de este tipo. Es para hacer una web donde se realizan tests, y para que no salgan todas las preguntas de golpe pienso que poner una o dos por página estaría bien, pero si hay alguna opción mejor estoy abierta.

Comment: Quiero pensar que deseas hacer algo como un `Step-form`, de ser así en Google hay bastantes ejemplos para poder crearlos, por ejemplo en el siguiente [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp) hay un ejemplo de cómo se implementan, las palabras clave a mi consideración podrían ser `Multi-step-form` para que puedas buscarlo

Comment: Sii, me refería a eso. No sabia que se llamaba así y por eso no me salía. Gracias!